# On an example of vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

In the book Elementary Differential Geometry of Christian Bar, on page 153 there is an example as follows:

Let $f: S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Since the first fundamental form is non-degenerate, there exists, for a fixed point $p$, exactly one vector $\nu(p)\in T_pS$ with the property $d_pf(X)=I(\nu(p), X)$. In this way, the gradient vector field $\nu:=\text{grad}\ f$ is defined.

In this example $S$ is a regular surface, $I$ is the first fundamental form,$d_pf$ is the differential map, $\nu: S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector field on $S$.

My questions are:

1. Why the first fundamental form is non-degenerate then we have exactly one vector $\nu(p)\in T_pS$ with the property $d_pf(X)=I(\nu(p), X)$?
2. From this how can we define the gradient vector field?

Answer (score 0):

The nondegeneracy condition means that the first fundamental form induces an isomorphism between vector fields and 1-forms. This is why one has exactly one vector field for each function: each function gives rise to a 1-form via its differential, and the isomorphism provided by the first fundamental form associated a unique vector field to it.

The definition of the gradient vector field is exactly this one: $\mathrm{grad}(f)$ is the unique vector field that satisfies $\mathrm{d}f(X)=g(\mathrm{grad}(f),X)$ for any vector field $X$ (here $g$ is the metric: for your purposes, the first fundamental form).